# Connecting to stardog with TrinityRDF, exception thrown if address other than localhost used

Tags: dotnetrdf, stardog

I get the following error on the line:

```
store.InitializeFromConfiguration(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ontologies.config"));
```

> A HTTP error  occurred while beginning a Transaction in the Store.
> No response, see aforementioned status line or inner exception for further details

Inner exception:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I get this error only when using the IP address of the stardog server on my network, not if I run the server on local host. Naturally my first thought was that the I had the IP address wrong, or there was a networking issue. I have however eliminated this possibility by using stardog studio to connect to the same IP address from the same machine. Additionally I can connect to the same machine using the DotNetRDFConsoleSample and the HttpApiConsoleSample, from the same machine.

I managed to reproduce this problem using the stardog example code for trinityRDF, (TrinityConsoleSample) to eliminate other errors.

This doesn't work:

```
const string connectionString = "provider=stardog;host=http://192.168.221.121:5820;uid=admin;pw=admin;sid=music";
```

Setting up a server on localhost and doing this does:

```
const string connectionString = "provider=stardog;host=http://localhost:5820;uid=admin;pw=admin;sid=music";
```

(I'll change the password before I deploy it)

Is this something I'm doing wrong or have I found a bug?